# A handful of errors in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I am doing an assignment on SQL using APEX, and I have encountered some errors, what have I done wrong?

[image]

below is my SQL code:
also I have included a picture with some of my code, and the respective errors that were displayed: the first part of the picture is an earlier build, and after some thorough research on what might have gone wrong, I changed my code to the code in the second part of the picture.

```
SELECT departments.department_id, employees.department_id, employees.employee_id, departments.department_name, employees.salary,
COUNT(employee_id)
FROM HR.employees, HR.departments
WHERE departments.department_id = employees.department_id
GROUP BY department_id;`
```

```
SELECT departments.department_id, employees.department_id, employees.employee_id, departments.department_name, employees.salary,
COUNT(*)
FROM HR.employees, HR.departments
WHERE departments.department_id = employees.department_id
GROUP BY department_id;`
```

Comment: Please post the errors you're getting...

Comment: my image didn't load the first time, but I edited it in

Comment: check the blue text :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Apex expert, but in the first query you are doing a COUNT without an appropriate GROUP BY clause.  You need to group by all the other columns that you aren't including in aggregate functions.

In the second one you are grouping by department_id, but you didn't specify whether it was departments.department_id or employees.department_id.  Pick one.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting (*column ambiguously defined*) is due to the following:

```
GROUP BY department_id;
```

You have multiple available columns named `department_id`, and it doesn't know which to select.  You will need to fully qualify the field (e.g.: `departments.department_id`)

But once you solve that issue, you'll have another - `GROUP BY` will require all non-aggregate fields to be included in the `GROUP BY` clause.

You should use the following as your `GROUP BY` statement (for your second posted example):

```
GROUP BY departments.department_id, 
         employees.department_id, 
         employees.employee_id, 
         departments.department_name, 
         employees.salary;
```